# How to pack two buttons of the same kind?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a simple contact list application, and I want that Tkinter places a button for every contact made.
This is the code I've made:

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk()
main.title("Contacts +")
main.geometry('420x300')
main.resizable(0,0)
contact_button = Button(text="NameExample")

contact_button.pack()
contact_button.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

I expected that Tkinter displays two buttons of the same kind, but he instead just shows one button.
Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the issue using clickable listboxes:

```
contactlist = Listbox(main,width=30)
contactlist.pack()
for names in namelist: contactlist.insert(END, names)
```

Comment: In your OP, you're talking about `Button`, but not `Listbox`.  Delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Much like if you want to eat two sandwiches you need to make two sandwiches, if you want to pack two buttons, you have to create two buttons.

```
contact_button_1 = Button(text="NameExample")
contact_button_2 = Button(text="AnotherExample")

contact_button_1.pack()
contact_button_2.pack()
```

Comment: You have duplicate `contact_button_1.pack()` should be `contact_button_2.pack()`

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [classes](https://realpython.com/python-classes/) are for. What you'll want to do is create a `class` for your contact button widget, then you can *instantiate* (use) that class as many times as you like.

```
from tkinter import *


class ContactButton(Button):  # define a class that inherits from tkinter.Button
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        # __init__ is the "setup" method for your class; it's called
        # automatically whenever you instantiate your class!
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)  # intialize the Button object
        # any other setup can be done inside this __init__ method
        # you can even 'pack' these buttons here like so:
        # self.pack(<put your pack args here>)
        # but it's usually better to leave packing separate from the widget itself

        
main = Tk()
main.title("Contacts +")
main.geometry('420x300')
main.resizable(0,0)

contact_button_1 = ContactButton(main, text="NameExample")
contact_button_1.pack()  # assuming you aren't packing in ContactButton.__init__()

contact_button_2 = ContactButton(main, text="Different Name")
contact_button_2.pack()  # assuming you aren't packing in ContactButton.__init__()

main.mainloop()
```

Here, `contact_button_1` and `contact_button_2` are both *instances* of the `ContactButton` class. `main` is passed in as the `parent` argument expected by `__init__`. Also notice that each instance of the class can accept the `text` parameter, but they don't have to have the same value.

The benefit here is that any widget that is an instance of your `ContactButton` class will inherit whatever features you define within that class. Classes (and more generally, Object Oriented Programming [OOP]) are used everywhere in UI programming because they allow you to define reusable objects, such as tkinter widgets!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by same kind? Let me assume that both the button have same text or both the button triggers same function. Whatever is the thing, when you want 2 buttons to be visible, you should declare them separately. But the configuration and packing you can do together using a for loop.

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk()
main.title("Contacts +")
main.geometry('420x300')
main.resizable(0,0)
btn1 = Button(main)
btn2 = Button(main)

for x in [btn1, btn2]:
    x.configure(text = 'NameExample', command = function_name)
    x.pack()
main.mainloop()
```